# Postgres index behaviour inconsistent when escaping underscore

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching

I have a user table with a text_pattern_ops index on the column key. The problem is that the data in the key column has underscores within it which need to be escaped. There are two ways (that I know of) to escape underscore, and only in one of these the index is actually used. Can anyone explain why this is so?

I have pasted the results of explain analyse for both the queries below.

Query 1:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select distinct userid from user
where userstatus IN ('Active')
and ( key like E'999999999_434153_%' or parentid = 434153) ;
```

QUERY PLAN:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=340685.17..340687.84 rows=267 width=4) (actual time=22678.760..22678.760 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on user  (cost=0.00..340684.50 rows=267 width=4) (actual time=22678.754..22678.754 rows=0 loops=1)
        Filter: (((userstatus)::text = 'Active'::text) AND (((key)::text ~~ '999999999_434153_%'::text) OR (parentid = 434153)))
Total runtime: 22678.879 ms
```

Query 2:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
select distinct userid from user
where userstatus IN ('Active')
and ( key like '999999999\\_434153\\_%' or parentid = 434153) ;
```

Produces a warning:

```
WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal
LINE 1: ...userstatus IN ('Active') and ( key like '999999999...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.
```

QUERY PLAN:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=344.50..347.17 rows=267 width=4) (actual time=226.127..226.127 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user  (cost=11.09..343.83 rows=267 width=4) (actual time=226.123..226.123 rows=0 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (((key)::text ~~ '999999999\\_434153\\_%'::text) OR (parentid = 434153))
        Filter: (((userstatus)::text = 'Active'::text) AND (((key)::text ~~ '999999999\\_434153\\_%'::text) OR (parentid = 434153)))
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=11.09..11.09 rows=84 width=0) (actual time=226.121..226.121 rows=0 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_key_idx  (cost=0.00..5.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=145.758..145.758 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (((key)::text ~>=~ '999999999_434153_'::text) AND ((key)::text ~<~ '999999999_434153`'::text))
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_parentid_key1  (cost=0.00..5.52 rows=84 width=0) (actual time=80.358..80.358 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: (parentid = 434153)
Total runtime: 226.256 ms
```

Comment: As *always*, your version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default of `standard_conforming_strings` is `on`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two levels of escaping.

1. Posix-style escaped strings `E'foo'`. Check your setting for [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS).
2. Pattern for [`LIKE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE), where `_` has a special meaning that can be escaped. I quote the manual:

> To match a literal underscore or percent sign without matching other
> characters, the respective character in pattern must be preceded by
> the escape character. The default escape character is the backslash
> but a different one can be selected by using the ESCAPE clause. To
> match the escape character itself, write two escape characters.

The index can only be used for left anchored patterns. If you have an underscore (`_`) in the middle of the pattern, the index cannot be used. Like in this pattern expression:

```
key like E'999999999_434153_%'
```

Unescaped `_` in the middle of the pattern, wildcard for any single character - may not be able to use a B-tree index with `text_pattern_ops`, especially in older versions. Also see [@Richard's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798851/postgres-index-behaviour-inconsistent-when-escaping-underscore/13799096#comment18980708_13799096).

In this pattern the `_` is escaped, which means it stands for a literal `_` and not as wildcard for a single character -> index not used.

```
key like '999999999\\_434153\\_%'
```

Assuming you have `standard_conforming_strings = OFF`. With `standard_conforming_strings = ON` this would result in a pattern looking for a literal `\` and a wildcard `_` which might not use the index either.

You may be interested in the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), which allows GiST or GIN indexes to support *any* `LIKE` expression. See:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)
- [How is LIKE implemented?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10856/3684)

Comment: Actually, I found the problem after posting the question. I need to escape the _ by using \\ (even if I am preceeding it by the E) so that the btree index is used . Once I do that the text_pattern_ops index will be used

Comment: A quick addition to Erwin's answer. I noticed the other day that the planner is actually smart enough to degrade to a bitmap index scan on >= 'ABC, <'ABD' if you have something like 'ABC_DEF%' and it thinks the statistics make sense.

Comment: @RichardHuxton: Good point, the first part is still left-anchored. Older versions may not be smart enough.

Comment: @sps: you should *really* switch to standard conforming strings (so you only need `\` not `\\`).